# How to create a Pyspark UDF for adding new columns to a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have some 5 columns to be added to the dataframe. (A - E) The values for these columns are stored in (a - e) variables.

Instead of using

```
 df.withColumn("A", a).withColumn("B", b).withColumn..... etc
```

Can we do this with a udf?

Currently I have named function :

```
     def add_col(df_name,newCol,value):
         df = df_name
         df = df.withColumn(newCol, value)
         return df
```

But I am not able to understand how to convert it to UDF and use it. Please help.

Comment: an UDF cannot produce more than 1 column... but you could return a complex column (of array or struct type). But apparently you are working with constant (literal) values, so I don't see the point of using an UDF

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add multiple columns you can use `select` with `*`:

```
df.select("*", some_column, another_column, ...)
```

Comment: how to insert values as well in the same step?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use UDF, they can't create multiple results.

However you can write select statement similar to this in other answer:

```
df.select(col("*"), lit(a).as("a"), lit(b).as("b"), ...)
```

You can also automate this adding:

```
val fieldsMap = Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b)
 df.select(Array(col("*")) ++ fieldsMap.map(e => lit(e._2).as(e._1)) : _*)
```